# Packing tkinter widgets breaks frame

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

So when ever I initialize my Gui class and then pack() my label and button widget the nice frame stylization I've configured with the frames they exist in breaks. Why is this if you comment out the pack of the button and label widgets it's exactly what I want it to look like.

```
class Gui(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        self.parent.wm_title("Conflict found")
        self.TV = 'Hello'
        # Creation
        self.statusbar = statusbar(self, bg="black", height=100, width=300)
        self.main = Main(self, bg="grey", height=50, width=300)

        # Packing
        self.statusbar.pack(side="top", expand=True)
        self.statusbar.label.pack()
        self.main.pack(side="bottom", expand=True)
        self.main.button.pack()

    def quit(self):
        self.parent.destroy()


class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Exit", command=self.quit)


class statusbar(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text=self.parent.TV, fg='white')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that this is how tkinter is designed to work. When you use `pack` or `grid`, tkinter will cause the parent window to grow or shrink to fit its children.

This is what you want 99.999% of the time because it lets you focus on the size of the widgets based on character sizes (or pixels when it matters, such as with images) and the GUI will be just the right size.

When you pick a specific size for frames and windows, your program won't look right if the user has different fonts, or a different OS, or a monitor with a different resolution, or the user tries to grow or shrink the window manually.

There are ways around this behavior, but you almost never want to turn this behavior off. The best solution is to focus on your interior widgets and let tkinter worry about the window size.

Instead of thinking "I need a statusbar that is 100 pixels tall and 300 pixels wide", think "I need a statusbar that has room for at least 20 characters, and fills the window horizontally". Tkinter will then do the right thing no matter what font, resolution, or OS you're using.

Answer (score 1):

The `height=` and `width=` of a Frame normally only apply if the Frame is empty.  As soon as you add any child widgets to it, its size gets recalculated to be the minimum needed to hold all the children.  To avoid this, you can call `.pack_propagate(0)` on the Frame (or `.grid_propagate(0)` if you're using `.grid()` on the children).