# Why doesn't the width of the frame show once ran?

Tags: python, tkinter

I specified a width for a frame, then I grid a button in it asking for it to be the widest it can using

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100, background="#ffffff")
frame.pack()
btn = Button(frame, text="Hello").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="we")
root.mainloop()
```

but it actually doesn't occupy the whole length of the frame, the frame is not even white. If I comment the button line it works just fine though.
Why is that?

Comment: You've told the Button to use the whole width of the Frame, but you haven't told the Frame to use the whole width of the window.  The normal behavior is for a Frame (or other container) to shrink to a size just big enough to hold its children.

Comment: It is because by default, frames will shrink or grow to fit their contents when using `pack` and `grid`.

Comment: This could be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/45359884/7432, though there are others that also address this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the commentors were telling you to do. Tell your frame not to propagate to grid.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root, width=500, height=500, background="red")
frame.pack()
frame.grid_propagate(0) # this fixes the frame issue you are having
btn = Button(frame, text="Hello")
btn.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="we")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It should be noted that this is rarely the right solution if your goals include creating a responsive UI.

Comment: Nice it works, now how do I make the buttons stay on the left?

Comment: I would heed what @BryanOakley has stated with respect to heading down this road. However, if you want to use grid to manage your widgets inside the frame then I would configure the rows and columns and then the widgets you want on the left should grid to the same column and separate rows.

Answer (score 0):

I can suppose that it because u place your button 'on' frame, not on root.
Hopefully, this will fix your problem:

```
btn = Button(root, text="Hello").pack()#.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="we")
```

Comment: This assigns `None` to `btn`

Comment: U can do this at different lines like this: 
    btn = Button(root, text="Hello");
    btn.pack()

Comment: The problem is that I want it to be just the whole frame

Comment: Ok so let's go in more detail. My program will have a leftmenu frame, with a "entries" labelframe and a "add entry" labelframe, the entries on top and the add entry on the bottom. the add entry will make you digit some parameters and then will update a dictionary with a new keypair being "name":{dictwithallparametersforthisentry}, then it makes a frame/entry with a label being the name and 2 buttons (one will delete the entry, the other one doesnt matter.)

Comment: i want all the entries to be aligned tho, and i need to be able to remove them singularly, not by for example deleting the entry on the dict and making a for loop for all the keys